# How do u change the scope of a local variable without using the global function?

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables

```
drink = input("What would you like? (espresso/latte/cappuccino): ")

money = 0
def price(drink):
    if drink == "espresso":
        money += 1.5
    elif drink == "latte":
        money += 2.0
    elif drink == "cappuccino":
        money += 3.0
    print(f"money = ${money}")

price(drink)
```

Hi I am aware that the variable `money` is a global variable but I'm not sure how do I edit the code without using the `global` function. Can someone explain how am I supposed to use the `return` function while updating the `money` variable?

Answer (score 0):

As you have expected, to pass a local variable to an *outer context* (as in, outside the function it was defined), you need to use the `return` *keyword* (just like `if`, `else`, `def`, that is a word that has a special meaning in the language).

```py
def price(drink):
    # here money is a local variable
    if drink == "espresso":
        money = 1.5
    elif drink == "latte":
        money = 2.0
    elif drink == "cappuccino":
        money = 3.0
    else:
        money = 0
    print(f"money = {money}")
    return money # we return this variable as a result
    

global_money = price(drink) # global_money is a global variable
```

To go further, a good question to ask yourself to detect unnecessary use of global variable is: "Do this variable need to be aware of something exterior to the function its defined in?"
If the answer is **no**, then it surely means it can be a local variable.
And if the answer is **yes**, you can probably pass this information via a *function argument* (like `drink` in your `price` function).

Let's take a new example, you want to add a 5$ addition to the prices for customers who are not regulars.

```py
# price has a new argument `is_a_regular_customer`
# it set to `True` if the customer is a regular, `False` otherwisee
def price(drink, is_a_regular_customer):
    money = 0 # money is still a local variable
    if not is_a_regular_customer:
        money += 5 # 5$ increase if not regular! outch
    # here money is a local variable
    if drink == "espresso":
        money += 1.5
    elif drink == "latte":
        money += 2.0
    elif drink == "cappuccino":
        money += 3.0
    print(f"money = {money}")
    return money
```

Last point, as you have noted I have removed the `$` when printing money with `print(f"money = {money}")`. In python, contrary to Javascript, you do not need to use `$` to perform *string interpolation*.